# Read a file codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, xcode-instruments

I need to read this file:

```
AVRAMOV P   ATALANTA    1   1   0
FREZZOLINI  P   ATALANTA    1   1   0
SPORTIELLO  P   ATALANTA    1   16  15
BIAVA   D   ATALANTA    8   9   1
EMANUELSON  D   ATALANTA    7   5   -2
STENDARDO   D   ATALANTA    7   9   2
BENALOUANE  D   ATALANTA    6   8   2
DRAME'  D   ATALANTA    5   5   0
```

I read this file, but I need to have some operation which I can work on string.
Anyone can suggest me any method?

Comment: Can you provide some more information? What format is the input, what operation are you looking to perform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what kind of string operation you're looking to do, but if you want to split the fields, you could do something like this:

```
<?php
$res = fopen('myfile.txt', 'r');
$data = array();

while (($line = fgets($res)) !== false) {
    $data[] = preg_split('/\s{2,}/', $line);
}

fclose($res);
```

This will create an array of lines, each line containing an array of fields separated by two or more spaces, for example:

```
[
    [
        'AVRAMOV',
        'P',
        'ATALANTA',
        '1',
        '1',
        '0'
    ],
    [
        'FREZZOLINI',
// ...
```